# xacro problem: kinectic 16.04 turtlebot2

Tags: turtlebot2, turtlebot, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

On a new install I have this message when launching "roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch"

```
xacro: Traditional processing is deprecated. Switch to --inorder processing!
To check for compatibility of your document, use option --check-order.
For more infos, see http://wiki.ros.org/xacro#Processing_Order
xacro.py is deprecated; please use xacro instead
```

It seems to work but I'm not sure. Can someone find a solution to this problem ?

Thanks

Goupil

PS: fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04, ros-kinetic-desktop-full, kinetic, turtlebot 2

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254595/xacro-problem:-kinectic-16.04-turtlebot2/) by [goupil35000](https://answers.ros.org/users/7096/goupil35000/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2017-02-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

These are *warnings*, not errors.

They basically tell you that the turtlebot xacro does not adhere to the current best practices (`--inorder`) and that the launch file uses the 'old' `xacro.py` instead of the `xacro` script.

As they are only warnings everything should still work.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [goupil35000](https://answers.ros.org/users/7096/goupil35000/) on 2017-02-14**:
Hi gvdhoorn,

Many thanks. It seems working.

Goupil

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-16**:
Question not answered?

**Comment by [goupil35000](https://answers.ros.org/users/7096/goupil35000/) on 2017-02-16**:
Yes question answered, but I don't find how to close this subject.

If you have an idea ... Thanks

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-16**:
We don't close questions here on ROS Answers when they are answered. Ticking the checkmark is better.

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2017-02-20**:
FYI, I added a ticked asking for a fix: https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot/issues/252